# Lessons in Play exercise question

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose that you play domineering (or cram) on two 8×8 chessboards. At your turn you can move on either chessboard (but not both!). Show that the second player can win

(Is it winning for the second player because we can consider the second board to be a 90 degree rotation of the first board (the board where the first move is made) and now the second player can just copy the moves of the first player (like mirror image stratergy) (after rotation)?

PS:There isnt any issue in asking textbook questions right?

DOmineering game : Domineering (also called Stop-Gate or Crosscram) is a mathematical game that can be played on any collection of squares on a sheet of graph paper. For example, it can be played on a 6×6 square, a rectangle, an entirely irregular polyomino, or a combination of any number of such components. Two players have a collection of dominoes which they place on the grid in turn, covering up squares. One player places tiles vertically, while the other places them horizontally Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domineering

Cram ruleset: Cram is a mathematical game played on a sheet of graph paper. It is the impartial version of Domineering and the only difference in the rules is that players may place their dominoes in either orientation, but it results in a very different game. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram_(game)